# Add php script to checkout success action (Magento)

Tags: php, magento, checkout

In Magento. How can I execute some php lines after the checkout confirmation.
Without writing them in `OnepageController.php : successAction() ?`

> (i'm developing a shipping module so I don't want to modify existing
>   files)

For example, In Opencart this can be done with `vqmod` (with xml files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a custom module.

add this in the layout xml of the module

```
<checkout_onepage_success>
    <reference name="checkout.success">
        <block type="[module]/[block]" name="some_name" as="some_name" template="[module]/success.phtml" />
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

Now you need to create the block with alias '[module]/[block]'. and the template `[module]/success.phtml` and add your logic in them.
You can even skip the creation of the block class and replace `[module]/[block]` with `core/template` and add your logic in `[module]/success.phtml` but it's cleaner with a block class.
Note: Don't use '[' and ']' in the block names and aliases. I put them there just to mark that those are placeholders.